# How to set up tea-time in emacs to use native notification system in gnome

Tags: gnome, emacs

Is there an easy way of having [`tea-time`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tea-time) display messages via gnome's native notification system?

The current "notification function" in tea-time.el is:

```
(defun show-notification (notification)
  "Show notification. Use mumbles."
 (if (program-exists "mumbles-send")
    (start-process "tea-time-mumble-notification" nil "mumbles-send" notification)
  (message notification)
 ))
```

I tried editing this to use `notify-send` instead, without any success: specifically using something like `(shell-command (concat "notify-send " notification))` in place of `(start-process "tea-time-mumble-notification" nil "mumbles-send" notification)` doesn't seem to work (I got rid of the if-statement as well, of course).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trial and error I figured out that the following redefinition works:

```
(defun show-notification (notification)
"Show notification. Use notify-send."
(start-process "tea-time-notify-notification" nil "notify-send" notification)
)
```

Fancier stuff can be done as well: using

```
(start-process "tea-time-notify-notification" nil "notify-send" "-i" (expand-file-name "~/path/to/your/icon/YourIconName.png") "Emacs Tea Timer" notification)
```

tells the notification daemon to use an icon ([this one](http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icon/101/tableware-icon-set/free-tea-cup-icon-png/) is suitable) in the notification pop-up and uses a emboldened 'summary' text ("Emacs Tea Timer").

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just call [`notify-send`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411620) command from the alert hook (if there is one, otherwise you might need to patch tea-time to have that.)

Comment: Thanks. I added more info in my original question: suggestions on how to call `notify-send`?

Comment: No idea.  Care to ask/search on some Emacs forum or search through emacswiki.org?

Comment: @BeSlayed :perhaps, redefine the cited function to use the suggested `notify-send` (instead of that `mumbles-send`)?

Comment: @imz: yes, I have tried `(defun show-notification (notification)
 (shell-command (concat "notify-send " notification)
))` (which seems like what you're suggesting), but I get a "Invalid number of options" error.

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs 24, you can use `notifications.el` to send D-Bus notifications directly from elisp code. Rewriting @yhager's hook, above:

```
(add-hook 'tea-time-notification-hook
  (lambda ()
    (notifications-notify :title "Time is up!"
                          :body "I know you're busy, but it's TEA TIME!!"
                          :app-name "Tea Time"
                          :sound-name "alarm-clock-elapsed)))
```

There are more useful args described on the [Notifications page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Notifications.html) of the [Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/) (including the `:sound-file` option, instead of `:sound-name`, which requires an [XDG sound theme implementation](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libcanberra/)).

Answer (score 1):

With the latest tea-time.el, you have a hook you can use for that.
Add to your Emacs initialization:

```
(add-hook 'tea-time-notification-hook 
  (function (lambda() 
    (start-process "tea-timer-notification" nil "notify-send" "Time is up!"))))
```